# Sort table in layout

Tags: android, tablerow

He was creating a table in order of listing data so orderly, but try it on a tablet is all messed up.

What I need is this, that you see in this example
[example](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table)

But what I have is this:

```
<TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView  android:layout_margin="1dip"
               android:id="@+id/txtNombre"
               android:layout_weight="0.3"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
               android:text="Celda1"/>
    <TextView  android:layout_margin="1dip"
               android:id="@+id/txtAsiento"
               android:layout_weight="0.3"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
               android:text="Celda2"/>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/icon1"/>
</TableRow>

<TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView android:layout_margin="1dip"
              android:id="@+id/txtTicket"
              android:layout_weight="0.3"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
              android:text="Celda1"/>
    <TextView android:layout_margin="1dip"
              android:id="@+id/txtNumero"
              android:layout_weight="0.3"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
              android:text="Celda2"/>
    <Button   android:id="@+id/button1"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="bottom"
              android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
              android:minHeight="20dip"
              android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
              android:shadowDx="0"
              android:shadowDy="0"
              android:shadowRadius="0"
              android:text="Escanear"
              android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
              android:textSize="15sp" />
</TableRow>
```

Completely unaware theme in android tables is why we take this opportunity to ask here if I'm doing well and if not, they can correct me or give me a good tutorial.

**EDIT**

[image]

What I need is that each item remains separated from the other and that also occupies the full width of the screen

Comment: What are you trying to achieve that's different from what this displays? Your example doesn't clarify what help you need.

Comment: @TedHopp I will upload an image to make it more clear

Comment: @TedHopp edit my post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set layout_width="0dp" and layout_weight="1" for every element, so then they will take the same space in the same proportion. Like this:

```
<TableRow
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView  android:layout_margin="1dip"
        android:id="@+id/txtNombre"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Celda1"/>
    <TextView  android:layout_margin="1dip"
        android:id="@+id/txtAsiento"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Celda2"/>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/icon1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</TableRow>
```

Anyway I really recommend you to not use TableRows and use a LinearLayout instead. Hope it help. Cheers!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer !, I really do not work, it is much smaller :(

Comment: What do you exactly mean with smaller?

Comment: The spaces between each element are made smaller, but took your advice and apply linear layout, design element and stay as expected.